# What are the template naming convention standards?

Tags: template

What is the standard for template naming conventions within a CMS?

Should the name be Structural (e.g. Two Column Template) or purpose based (e.g. News Template) or something else?

It makes sense to me that the name be structural based, but I would like to know what the standard is here before we proceed with this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've seen, they generally go with the structural formula:

Simple:

```
[navigation-top/left/right] + [content L/R/C align]
```

Advanced:

```
[columns] + [navigation-top/left/right] + [rows*]
```

*rows can be split further into more columns, such that there can be a full-width (photograph or chart) and then two columns below of text.

To directly answer your question: **What is the standard for template naming conventions within a CMS?**

- There isn't a global standard. We'd need to know which CMS you are using. Plus, why would the name carry any significance if the layout would be the same `(2-column vs. news template)`?

***The Digitalus CMS uses this approach:***

[image: digitalus example layout structural]

***While there can be a completely modular approach:***

[image: modular approach without names. graphical]

***Magento, with intention-based naming:***

[image: magento layouts]

So as you can see, it really varies with the CMS being used.

Comment: To answer your question ionFish of why would the name carry any significance? This would mean that editors within our CMS would know what template to select when creating a new page. Having a structural name as you suggest would be more relevant than a purpose based design.

Comment: @jaslr - That leaves it to personal preference. You should first, actually speak with your editors and see which they are more comfortable using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any single standard apart from "whatever works best for this particular project". My personal preference is to name the templates according to their intended use, for example `News article`, `Search results`, `Product page` or `Blog post`.